# How to solve integral with cubic polynomial at the denominator with Byrd-Friedman's handbook of elliptical integrals?

Tags: integration, polynomials, complex-integration, elliptic-integrals

Is there an equivalent elliptic integral (with solution) in the Byrd-Friedmann's elliptical integral Handbook? This is the integral:

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-p)(x-q)(x-̅q)}}dx $$

where we have three roots p>0 and q=a+ib and q̅=a-ib (complex conjugated of q) ; a,b>o and $i=\sqrt{-1}$.
The roots come from a cubic polynomial and I am looking for a solution incl. steps. For instance, in my previous question and thanks to the members of math.stack, I solved a similar integral containing a quartic polynomial at the denominator (therefore four roots): I used the solution proposed by the integral 260.00 of the mentioned book. The integral has been classified as an incomplete elliptical integral of the first order. What about this case?

Any proposal would be very appreciated. Thank you so much for your support. Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Byrd-Friedman formula 239.00 covers the case
$$
\int_a^y \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(t-a)[(t-b_1)^2+a_1^2]}} = g F(\varphi,k);\quad y>a
$$
as an elliptic integral of the first kind. In your case $(x-q)(x-\bar q)=(x-\Re q)^2+\Im^2 q$.
The auxiliary variable are (note that $a$ here is your $p$)
$$
A^2\equiv (b_1-a)^2+a_1^2.
$$
$$
g\equiv 1/\surd A.
$$
$$
k^2=(A+b_1-a)/(2A)
$$
$$
\cos\varphi = \frac{A+a-y}{A-a+y}.
$$
and a complementary formula 241.00
$$
\int_y^\infty \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(t-a)[(t-b_1)^2+a_1^2]}} = g F(\varphi,k);\quad \infty> y\ge a
$$
where
$$
A^2\equiv (b_1-a)^2+a_1^2.
$$
$$
g\equiv 1/\surd A.
$$
$$
k^2=(A+b_1-a)/(2A)
$$
$$
\cos\varphi = \frac{y-a-A}{y-a+A}.
$$
See also https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000615533 .

Comment: I am very thankful for your support. You are a great and gentle mathematician. I hoped to receive exactly a comment from you. You expanded my knowledge of elliptical integrals starting from your previos answer in the previous question as I was not aware of the handbook of integrals at that time. Also this time I found what I was looking for.